# Passing rvalue as const& reference

Tags: c++, regex, rvalue, qregexp

Assume there is `QRegExp regex` (wildcard) and `QDirIterator dit`. If they are identical, .i.e. they should match. Why does this

```
QString s = dirIterator.fileName();
if(ignore.exactMatch(s))
    continue;
```

match and the following not:

```
if(ignore.exactMatch(dirIterator.fileName()))
    continue;
```

I dont see anydifference, except that exact match accepts a const ref and  in the latter case there is a rvalue. But this shouldnt matter, should it?

Comment: I can't answer, as I don't know QRegExp, but from my experience with overloading operators, `const <type> rhs` and `<type> rhs` are completely different, and that makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: Nothing obvious stands out. What compiler are you using? Are you *sure* that this is the actual code that failing? For example the same filename does match in both cases but something else is behaving differently?

Comment: I debugged it dozens of times. The second fails. gcc 5.2